# Simplify the following expressions using fractional exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Simplify the following expressions using fractional exponents. Display your answer using fractional exponents.

$${ \sqrt[ 3 ]{x^{ 7 }} = }\text{  and  }{ \sqrt[ 7 ]{x^{ 3 }} = }$$

Thanks..not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

${\Large \sqrt[ 3 ]{x^{ 7 }} = x^{7/3}} $ and ${\Large \sqrt[ 7 ]{x^{ 3 }} = x^{3/7} }$  since  ${\Large \sqrt[ s ]{x}=x^{1/s}}$ and ${\Large(x^{a})^{b}=x^{ab}}$.

Comment: Oh right totally forgot you could so that thanks!